# SVN commit problem

Tags: svn

I'm using netbeans and recently when i tried to commit my changes i got this error message:

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Permission denied
Commit failed (details follow):
Can't move '/home/********/svn/db/txn-protorevs/1000-sk.rev' to '/home/**********/svn/db/revs/1/1001': Permission denied
```

Comment: Guess: You're using svn+ssh and the permissions have gotten all screwed up. Kreker below is probably on the right track if thats the case. You'll need to run the commands on the SVN server with sufficient perms.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

check the permission to the file or better to the dir. 
Use

```
ls -l
```

for seeing the owner

```
chown -R owner.group /path
```

Chown is for changing the owenr/group. Change with your values.
Instaed you can set all the permision to 777. In linux this always works but it's not very stylish:)

```
chmod 777 -R /path
```

In both case the -R stand for recusirve. Means that it affects all the subdirs and files too

Comment: For me, I encountered the same problem.  The fix above to change permissions recursively throughout the entire repository folder structure on the SVN server resolved the issue.

The cause was running 'svnadmin load' as root instead of as the user that apache runs as (and has the correct permissions and ownership of all the SVN repository files/folders).  Probably documented, but be careful with svnadmin commands!

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that it says "Permission Denied", it seems as though your credentials don't have permission in SVN to write in the destination folder

Answer (score 0):

Is this referring to paths on your local file system, or paths in the remote subversion repo? does it have something to do with the file permissions, or which user the "svn" task is running as? Is this on windows?

It sounds to me like there's a problem with your local filesystem, that the user running the SVN command doesn't have the necessary write privs. Maybe you checked out the project as "root", and you're trying to commit as "mohammedj" or something

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a process around that was keeping the file locked. Closing suspicious apps may solve the problem, even try rebooting if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Error indicates that you don't have enough permissions to write to the particular repository. For permissions issues you should contact to repository administrator. The bottom line is you don't have enough permissions to perform the operation.